# Send message to kafka to multiple partitions and listening multiple same consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to understand how to write from a producer to multiple partitions? Did I do the right? Is maybe have easy decision?
I have 2 partiotions in my topic.
And i want read same message type equals consumers

How can I receive the same message in the consumers without specifying the partition number in the producer and the consumer?

Thanks.
Producer

```
@Service
public class Producer {
   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

   @Autowired
   private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

   @Value("${app.topic.foo}")
   private String topic;

   public void send(String message){
      LOG.info("sending message='{}' to topic='{}'", message, topic);
      kafkaTemplate.send(topic,0, "1",  message);
      kafkaTemplate.send(topic, 1, "1", message);
   }
}
```

Consumer 1

```
@Service
public class Consumer {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

  @KafkaListener(
          groupId = "reflectoring-group-3",
          topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                  topic = "${app.topic.foo}",
                  partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(
                          partition = "0",
                          initialOffset = "0") }))
  void commonListenerForMultipleTopics(String message) {
      LOG.info("MultipleTopicListener - {}", message);
  }
}
```

Consumer 2

```
@Service
public class Consumer2 {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer2.class);

  @KafkaListener(
          groupId = "reflectoring-group-3",
          topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                  topic = "${app.topic.foo}",
                  partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(
                          partition = "1",
                          initialOffset = "0") }))
  void commonListenerForMultipleTopics(String message) {
      LOG.info("MultipleTopicListener - {}", message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Did I do the right?

You're needlessly duplicating information in the topic, but sure. You can check with `kafka-console-consumer --partition` CLI, for example.

> receive the same message in the consumers without specifying the partition number

You cannot. For instance, if you set unique groupId, then you would get events from all partitions. Or, if you remove `parititonOffsets` and use parameter of `Message` or `ConsumerRecord` rather than String, then you still need to manually filter on `message.partition() == X`